# How to print contents of an hash table?

Tags: c#

I've an hash table with the details as mentioned below

```
public void get_Unique_Sequence(List<string> name, List<List<string>> nameSequence)
{
     Hashtable test = new Hashtable();

     test.Add(nameSequence, name)

     foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in test)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to print the contents of the hash table with the help of foreach loop. However the output which I'm getting is

output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Please guide me to get the key and value (that is the contents) of the hashtable.

Comment: You will have to cast the key and value to `List<string>` and iterate over them to print them. The `ToString()` of a `List<T>` is "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]"

Comment: This code looks like weird to my eyes. I can harldy see any scenario where you can use a list as a key. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `HashTable` is effectively depreciated as of .NET 2.0.  You should be using a `Dictionary` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to insert the lists objects in the hash table, but the elements in the list.

So first you have to do something like:
(assuming that the list are not null and have the same size)

```
   for(int i =0;i<name.Count;i++){
       test.Add(nameSequence[i], name[i]);
   }
```

instad of:

```
   test.Add(nameSequence, name);
```

And then your method should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would like to format the output, but to print the content of a List you have to iterate on it.

On the List of lists you need to iterate two times.

Maybe a solution could be this:

```
public void get_Unique_Sequence(List<string> name, List<List<string>> nameSequence)
{
    Hashtable test = new Hashtable();

    test.Add(nameSequence, name);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in test)
    {
        string key = string.Empty;

        foreach (string s in (List<string>)entry.Key)
        {
            key += s + " "; 
        }

        foreach (List<string> list in (List<List<string>>)entry.Value)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            foreach (string s in list)
            {
                value += s + " ";
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to format the output according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue isn't about printing the hashtable. It's about printing a `List<List<string>>`.

You want something like this for each key and value:

```
foreach (var sublist in result)
{
    foreach (var obj in sublist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code I'm getting Error message: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @dexter This is just a guess since I can't see your code, but you need to cast the object back to a `List<List<string>>` before you can call `foreach` on it. Selman does it in his post: `foreach (string y in ((List<List<string>>)entry.Value).SelectMany(x => x))` but uses LINQ to reduce the number of loops necessary. The relevant bit in our case is the casting.

Comment: I tried Selman's code, I got an exception for the Values : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Stri‌​ng]]'.

Comment: @dexter You need to edit your OP and show the code you're referring to. It is extremely difficult to figure out what you're doing wrong this way.